How do I remove my Frilans Finans/Invoicery account?
A few years ago I used a service called Frilans Finans (or Invoicery in English). I haven't had any use for it since then and I would now like to remove my account. However, I can't find any information about how to actually do this. I combed through the settings of my account page and tried searching for a guide on how to delete my account, but I couldn't find anything.
Eventually, after searching around, I found this: https://jobb.frilansfinans.se/en-GB/request_removal
However, it seems to be about removing information about yourself if you've applied to work at the company, not if you've used them to receive invoices (note how it's on a different subdomain). I tried entering my email anyway but I've yet to receive any response, so I'm not counting on anything.
How can I remove my account on this website? I'm in the EU so I should have the right to be forgotten.

I sent them an email about this and they replied to me with that to delete your account you have to send them an email, and that since I requested to have my account deleted in that email, they will now go ahead and remove it. I couldn't find any public documentation explaining this, but I guess that answers the question then.
